# Warning when building with wrong configuration

Tags: visual-studio

After a few mistake builds with the Release configuration pushing stuff to other environments I'd like to have a warning or prompt of some sort to stop me from doing such madness if I don't really want to.

Is there a way to make this happen? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I can see of doing this is to leverage the **Build Events** dialog in the Project Settings.

First add a file called **usermessage.vbs** to the solution. It should contain the following:

```
a = MsgBox("Continue with Debug Build",1,"Build Configuration Warning")
if a=1 then WScript.Quit(0) Else WScript.Quit(1) End If
```

This will present an OK/Cancel dialog which returns an error unless you click **OK**.

Add this code to the **Pre-build event command line**:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug WSCRIPT.EXE "$(SolutionDir)usermessage.vbs"
```

This will run the script if you build in debug configuration.
The script will error and the build will halt unless you click **OK** in the dialog.